# NZEC Runtime Error in Python 2.7 in SPOJ

Tags: python, runtime-error

I think my algo is right(may be done very badly) But I get the desired outputs in ideone.com. But in SPOJ it keeps on saying "Runtime Error NZEC". Please suggest a few changes to get this right.

Here is the link to the Question :

http://www.spoj.com/problems/RAFANOLE/

Here is my code :

```
import sys;
inp=sys.stdin.read().split("\n");
t=int(inp[0]);
i=1;
g_N=dict();
g_D=dict();
t_N=dict();
t_D=dict();
while(i<t+2):
    a=inp[i].split();
    game_N =0;
    curr_N =0;
    game_D =0;
    curr_D =0;
    tie_N=0;
    tie_D=0;
    k=0;
    n=len(a);
    while ((k<n)and((game_N<6)or(game_D<6))):
        if(a[k]=='N'):
            curr_N = curr_N +1;
            if(curr_N==4 and curr_D < 3):
                game_N=game_N +1;
                curr_N=0;
                curr_D=0;
            if(curr_N==3 and curr_D ==3) :
                while(a[k]!=a[k+1]):
                    k=k+1;
                if(a[k]=='N'):
                    game_N=game_N+1;
                    curr_N=0;
                    curr_D=0;
        if(a[k]=='D'):
            curr_D=curr_D+1;
            if(curr_D==4 and curr_N<3):
              game_D=game_D+1;
              curr_D=0;
              curr_N=0;
            if(curr_N==3 and curr_D ==3) :
               while(a[k]!=a[k+1]):
                   k=k+1;
               if(a[k]=='D'):
                   game_D=game_D+1;
                   curr_N=0;
                   curr_D=0;
        k=k+1;
        if (game_N==6 and game_D ==6):
            break;
    if((game_N==6 and game_D==5 ) or (game_N==5 and game_D==6)):
        curr_N=0
        while(game_N != 7 and game_D != 7):
            if (a[k]=='N'):
                curr_N=curr_N+1;
            if(a[k]=='D'):
                curr_D=curr_D+1;
            if(curr_N==4 and curr_D<3):
                game_N=game_N+1;
            if(curr_D==4 and curr_N<3):
                game_D=game_D+1;
    if (game_N==6 and game_D ==6):
        while (1):
            if(a[k]=='N'):
                tie_N=tie_N+1;
            if(a[k]=='D'):
                tie_D=tie_D+1;
            if(((tie_D==7 or tie_N==7) and (abs(tie_D-tie_N)>=2)) or ((tie_D>7 or tie_N>7)and(abs(tie_D-tie_N)>=2))):
                break;
            k=k+1;

    if(tie_N>tie_D):
        game_N=game_N+1;
    elif(tie_N<tie_D) :
        game_D=game_D+1;
    g_N[i]=game_N;
    g_D[i]=game_D;
    t_N[i]=tie_N;
    t_D[i]=tie_D;

    i=i+2;
i=1;
while(i<t+2):        
    if(g_N[i]>g_D[i]):
        if(t_N[i]==0 and t_D[i] ==0):
            print ("N %d" % g_N[i]);
            print ("D %d" % g_D[i]);
            print "\t";
        else :
            print ("N %d(%d-%d)"%(g_N[i],t_N[i],t_D[i]));
            print ("D %d" % g_D[i]);
    else:
        if(t_N[i]==0 and t_D[i] ==0):
            print ("D %d" % g_D[i]);
            print ("N %d" % g_N[i]);
        else :
            print ("D %d(%d-%d)"%(g_D[i],t_D[i],t_N[i]));
            print ("N %d" % g_N[i]);
    i=i+2;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not considering the fact that the input data ends. `sys.stdin` is a file like object and requires an EOF character to mark the end. As it is not present, python tries to read more data when none is present and you get an error.

You should use `input` or `raw_input` instead of `sys.stdin`. As an example, in the code above, replace the 2<sup>nd</sup> and the 3<sup>rd</sup> lines with (assuming you use Python 2.7)

```
t = input("")
```

Also replace the first line in the first `while` with

```
a = input("")
```

Comment: If the program doesnt error out, exit code will be 0 by default.